# Refresh whole view in android?

Tags: android

I am calling Web API, we store the response in preferences, whenever we go back to the other screen that time reload and get this response from preferences and display, but at a same time we need to call web API in background and when response is returned successfully again store in preferences and refresh new data on my screen.

Please explain how this is possible.

Comment: Every time show the data from SharedPreference and call the WS every time and on data loaded from WS store it and refresh the data. That's it!

Comment: if you mean to restart the application view from any of event according to your logic you may use

Comment: No need to refresh just write your code in onResume() method

Comment: my question is, i  want to load data from prefrence,, because some time  WS response get more time ,, that's while i think to store data in prefrence and  load from the prefrences,, and new WS response store in prefrence ,, after storing automatically new data display on screen,,, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple just create methods and call whenever you want.

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            getDataFromPreference();
            getDataFromWebAPI();
    }


    public void getDataFromPreference()
    {
        //featch all data from preference and display on view
    }

    public void getDataFromWebAPI()
    {
        //featch all data from web API

        //Write your data into preference
        getDataFromPreference();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to refresh the view as a whole, put the code that sets up the view into a function, which you can then call when needed. In your case, that would be in the `onResume()` method of your Activity/Fragment and then also when the API call finishes.

Example:

```
private void refreshDisplayUsername() {
    String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
    usernameView.setText(username);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    refreshDisplayUsername();
}

// Put this code wherever you're handling the API response
public void onAPICallFinished() {
    // Store data into SharedPrefs here

    refreshDisplayUsername();
}
```